# Creating a shadow DOM with template binding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

**Context.**

I am trying to create Web components using just the platform facilities in webcomponents.js but not those in the polymer layer (polymer.js). Typical examples are simple and work fine:

```
<div id="wc-1">
    <span id="text">View</span>
</div>
<template id="template">
  <div>
    <h2> <content select="#text"> Default </content> 1 </h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
     function createWC (host) {
       var host  = document.querySelector (host);
       var template = document.querySelector ('#template'); 
       var root = host.createShadowRoot ();
       root.appendChild (template.content.cloneNode (true));  
     }     
     var wc = createWC ('#wc-1');
  });

</script>
```

**Problem.**

Extending the example above with `template bindings` and a typical activating script (1), some undesired outcomes are obtained. The next code results in two copies of the template content, one due to the activating code and another with un resolved data-bindings within the `Shadow DOM`. How can I achieve to activate the template and include its contents within the `shadow DOM`?

```
<div id="wc-1">
    <span id="text">View</span>
</div>
<template id="template" bind="{{data}}">
    <div class="red">
        <h2> <content select="#text"> Default </content> 1 </h2>
        Created @{{now}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    function createWC (host) {
      var host  = document.querySelector (host);
      var template = document.querySelector ('#template'); 
      var root = host.createShadowRoot ();
      template.model = { // (1)
        data : {
           now : new Date()
        }
      };
      root.appendChild (template.content.cloneNode (true));
    }
    var wc = createWC ('#wc-1');
  });
</script>
```

**Question.**

I suppose I have a mistake in the activating section. Can anybody help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance. Code can be find at http://jsbin.com/tiniyu/5/edit

Answer (score 2):

You're linking to an old version of `platform.js` (0.3.4). It looks like in the latest version of `platform.js` (0.4.2) template binding has been removed (the same should be true for webcomponents.js v0.4.2).

Here's an example using the master branch of platform from the polymer site: http://jsbin.com/pejoga/2/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. Then, do you mean that, even importing polymer.js, it is imposible to create shadow DOMS with template binding without using the custom tags standard?

Answer (score 0):

The `{{x}}` syntax is not part of the `<template>` specification, but is instead part of the Polymer library. If you are trying to not use Polymer, then it will not work for you.

By itself, [template does very little](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-template-element). Polymer adds code that looks for `<template>` elements, looks for attributes or nodes containing `{{x}}` syntax, and messes with them.

Comment: Thanks Domenic, I know that data bindings are not part of the standard but as I say in my post I am using just webcomponents.js with template binding and it works properly. It proves that data-bindings are not implemented at polymer.js level but at platform level. What I am questioning is how to apply the activation within a shadow DOM

Comment: Hmm I guess I don't understand webcomponents.js then, I thought it only contained standard features ... that's very strange.

Comment: All template-binding support comes from TemplateBinding.js and is not native in any platform. Whatever Javier has discovered is a false positive.

Comment: Thanks Scott, What I am trying to do is to create a multi-layered component by invoking several times createShadowRoot and using different templates with data-bindings for each layer. Is there any way to do that at the platform level? If not, is there any way to achieve my purpose at the polymer.js level? After your comment, I realize that now template binding technology can be used only at the polymer.js level but, up to my knowledge, at that level, it is impossible to create components with several layers. Am I right? I would appreciate your comments a lot.